# Is it possible to open a case for a (smart) group of contacts?

Tags: civicase

I've defined a smart group and I've defined a case type. And now I'd like to open this case type for all contacts in a smart group. Is this possible? The alternative would be to click into each contact in the smart group, one at a time, go to actions and select add case. This would be overly time-consuming and monotonous for a smart group containing a large number of contacts, e.g., a smart group populated by users who have downloaded content from CMS and now require some follow-up. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CiviRules with a Daily trigger for group members (and then just get rid of the rule afterwards if you don't want this to add cases for new group members). If you do, you could add a condition to check for the case and only add it if it isn't already there.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem like use of CiviRules may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if it works with cases but you could use https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui to import a csv file. You just need to export the contact ids from your smart group first and then use that in your import file.